# does systemverilog support linked lists?

Tags: linked-list, verilog, system-verilog

I tried implementing a circular doubly-linked list class (with a single sentinel node) in systemverilog. The list itself seems to work as expected but ends up crashing the simulator (corrupting stack?)

This led me to wonder if this is something fundamentally unsupported by the language (in terms of allocation)? SV does have a "queue" construct that can be made to work in the same way (probably more efficient in both access and insertion time).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

SystemVerilog does have a queue construct. They're declared a bit like arrays, but use the `$` symbol:

```
int myqueue[$];   // $ indicates a queue

myqueue.push_front(14);
some_int = myqueue.pop_back();
```

Depending how you use combinations of methods `push_front()`, `push_back()`, `pop_front()` and `pop_back()`, you can implement stacks & FIFOs and the like. A quick internet search should give you a full list of methods and declaration options.

I doubt that SystemVerilog queues are synthesizable. And I'm not 100% sure how you'd go about making a circular buffer from one without checking indices first...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inherently missing from the language that I'm away of. Pretty much everything is pass by reference, so that's the main thing you need. Only gotcha I can think of is to remember that SV is garbage collected, so it's important to null out your references to instances when they're removed from your list (but you'd probably do that anyway)

I'm pretty sure the queue would be implemented as a linked list internally. That said I've had some issues on different simulators when I've wanted to use queues in weird and wonderful ways.

Answer (score 1):

SystemVerilog is a garbage-collected language.  Circularly linked lists have the potential to cause issues if the garbage collection scheme implemented by the simulator you are using is buggy.